# Creating google oauth X.509 certificate in PEM format within Mac OS X

Tags: macos, oauth, certificate, x509, authsub

I am currently in the process of setting up the Google oauth for my site and I was wondering if it is possible to generate a X.509 certificate in PEM format within MAC OS X via terminal?

Google provides this page as reference:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html#Registered

but I was hoping it could be done within the Mac OS instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use OpenSSL for that, it should be installed by default on OS X. This [tutorial](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) shows you how you may create your own self-signed certificate.

You can also use OpenSSL for something more sophisticated, e.g. a root CA that would issue either further sub-CAs or end-entity certificates directly.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is dead.